# When running two devices in parallel is the amperage always split exactly 50/50?

Tags: voltage, parallel, amperage

I have a AC to DC adaptor that outputs 12V 3A.

This came with a USB HDD dock which has two slots.

I want to splice a 12V fan into the wire in parallel so they are both powered by the same wall plug.

Will the fan just use however many amps it needs and leave the rest for the USB HDD dock or will it only be possible for each device to get 12V 1.5A now because they are in parralell?

Comment: Not always.....

Comment: If they were in series they would have the same current.  In parallel they will have the same voltage and the current will depend on the requirement of each device.  If the total requirement for current is less than the 3A available you should be OK.

Comment: I think we can savely require Ohm's law to be known on an *engineering* site?

Comment: Though experiment again: I want to put a 5 W mains lamp into one of my ceiling lights. I have a 2 kW kettle. When I switch them both on at the same time will they both get the same power?

Comment: 12 V Computer fans are <~3W or 0.25A so the HDD is also about the same except on startup, so no problem!!  Your supply is rated for 36W=12x3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the currents will be limited to 3 A. As with any power supply, it is the user's responsibility to ensure that the total remains below the spec'd limit. Power supplies have a wide range of behaviors when the current limit is exceeded, any of which may disrupt operation of downstream components, so overloading should be avoided.

Comment: "graceful" is subjective here - for USB devices, shutdown could be considered more graceful than devices seeing an out-of-spec reduced voltage.

Comment: So lets assume that with 1 drive docked the USB HDD Dock draws 2A at peak under load. In theory I would be safe to draw up to 1A for the fan that I have wired in parallel?

Comment: @elltg: Yes, the constraint is on the sum of the currents, not the individual current components.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was trying to ask.

Comment: @nanofarad: You're right, I could have chosen a less colloquial word. I was mentally comparing something like a linear regulator to a supply equipped with an over-I protection that disables the supply when the current threshold is exceeded. I'll edit the original answer to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the fan just use however many amps it needs and leave the rest for the USB HDD dock?

Yes.  That's what will happen.  In fact, the USB HDD dock will take what *it* needs, and very likely leave the total current draw less than 3A (assuming it doesn't need more than 1.5A).

> or will it only be possible for each device to get 12V 1.5A now because they are in parallel?

There seems to be some misunderstanding out there about the whole volts & amps things work.  If you have a device that consumes 1A from a 12V supply, then that's what it'll do -- whether the supply is rated at 1A or 100A.  If you put it in parallel with another device that consumes 5A from a 12V supply, then together -- assuming they don't try to pull more current than the supply can, well, supply, the total current will be 6A.

Basically, a device can only "see" the voltage applied -- it can't see any other devices connected to the same power rail.  So it'll always pull the same current for the same voltage.